# Отсутствие href у ссылки

Tags: html

Правильно ли не присваивать атрибут href ссылке если работаю с ней через JS?

Пример тому модальное окно. У верстальщика привычка на все ссылки ставить заглушки  в виде `#`.После клика на такие ссылки в URL адрессе остаются эти решетки которые никому не нужны.

```
div id="modal-forgot" class="modal-forgot modal styled1 form-dynamic">           
    <div class="modal-content">
      <h4>Public holidays</h4>
      <a href="#" class="modal-action modal-close btn_close"><i class="icon-close"></i></a>
      <div class="parent-form holidays-box">
        <div class="display-table">
            <div class="thead">
                <div class="tr">
                    <div class="th">HOLIDAY NAME</div>
                    <div class="th">PERIOD / DATE</div>
                    <div class="th">&nbsp;</div>
                    <div class="th">&nbsp;</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="tbody">

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-foot">
            <button type="button" data-where='#form2 .tbody' class="btn waves-effect waves-block w-auto">Add New Holiday</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->   
</div><!-- /.modal-forgot -->
```

Comment: Вы что-то не то делаете, раз при клике через JS у вас  в браузере появляется `#` ... в скрипте должно быть либо `return false` либо `preventDefault()` и т.п........ а ссылка без `href` это обычный тег.... в таком случае какой смысл вообще делать ссылку? проще сделать обычный тег и применить к нему стили как ссылке

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, там возможно на конкретные теги завязаны стили используемой библиотеки

Comment: @Grundy про какие-либо библиотеки я не увидел ничего в вопросе. А вы?......но все равно, решетка не появляется если в скрипте  ретёрн написать как минимум......и если это самопал...то ссылка вообще не нужна

Comment: Это модальное окно от материалайза

Comment: @quaresma89 собссн этот ваш самый материалайз не оставляет решеток в Url  при нажатии..... это приводит к выводу, что просто не так что-то делаете

Comment: @quaresma89 попробовал написать вместо `a` другой тег... `div` и все работает https://jsfiddle.net/cbvdcv85/ ........ то есть как я и сказал для работы даже не обязательно чтоб тег был ссылкой в принципе.. достаточно назначить нужные классы...

Comment: не знаю почему но у меня остаются решетки в урл

Comment: @quaresma89 значит нужно смотреть что в коде JS пишите ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 3):

[Выдержка из спецификации](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/links.html#links):

> **NOTE:** The href attribute on a and area elements is not required; when those elements do not have href attributes they do not create hyperlinks.

То есть, `href` не обязательный атрибут, но при его отсутствии браузер не будет рассматривать тег `a` как ссылку.

Comment: А мне это и не надо,зачем нужна индексация линка который совершает лишь закрытие модального окна!

Comment: @quaresma89, вообще говоря браузер не индексирует :-)

Comment: Я поправил ответ,поисковые системы)